# Why doesn't my clip-path work?

Tags: ember.js, svg, clipping

In my ember app, I have a dynamic route such as

router.js

```
this.resource('reports', function() {
  this.resource('type', { path: '/type/:type_id' });
});
```

This would give me a complex url such as:

```
localhost:8080/reports/type/1234
```

In my template I have this code defining my clipPath

```
<svg class="svg-container">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="bound" >
      <rect width="20" height="30" x="300" y="300" > </rect>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>


  <path d="M32.00000000108507,....(truncated for readability)" 
    stroke-width="2px" 
    clip-path="url(reports#type#54235231673b1b7759694bb2#bound)" 
    class="line greenline" style="stroke: rgb(192, 57, 43);">
  </path>
</svg>
```

And the clipping path doesn't work. I suspect it is related to an ember routing issue as simply making the URL "url(#bound)" doesn't work either. Any thoughts?

Comment: Updated the example and the quotes don't address the issue

Comment: I don't think you have a valid url you can't have multiple fragments (i.e # characters)

Comment: The only reason I know of that would prevent `url(#bound)` from working is if you have a `<base href="…">` element in your HTML. Was that the case?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the problem! I was generating my url() attribute incorrectly. The correct url for the clipPath given my route is

```
clip=path="url(reports/type/1232#bound)"
```

Note using the actual URL as the resource